# how can I insert database into my nextjs program

Tags: sql, typescript, next.js, prisma, next.js13

The thing is I was practicing postgresql to nextjs integration but when I try to create an account it has this error 405 according to the else condition.

this is the error in the browser console:

```
page.tsx:14 
        
        
        POST http://localhost:3000/api/auth/signup net::ERR_ABORTED 405 (Method Not Allowed)
handleSubmit @ page.tsx:14
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:19462
invokeGuardedCallbackImpl @ react-dom.development.js:19511
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:19586
invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError @ react-dom.development.js:19600
executeDispatch @ react-dom.development.js:30652
processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder @ react-dom.development.js:30684
processDispatchQueue @ react-dom.development.js:30697
dispatchEventsForPlugins @ react-dom.development.js:30708
eval @ react-dom.development.js:30898
batchedUpdates$1 @ react-dom.development.js:23767
batchedUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:27614
dispatchEventForPluginEventSystem @ react-dom.development.js:30897
dispatchEvent @ react-dom.development.js:28670
dispatchDiscreteEvent @ react-dom.development.js:28641
```

while this is in my vscode terminal:

```
` ⨯ Detected default export in 'C:\Users\USER\Desktop\myWorks\webdevproj\loginsys\src\app\api\auth\signup\route.ts'. Export a named export for each HTTP method instead.⨯ No HTTP methods exported in 'C:\Users\USER\Desktop\myWorks\webdevproj\loginsys\src\app\api\auth\signup\route.ts'. Export a named export for each HTTP method.
```

```
this is my code for my api to POST data  

 import prisma from "@/lib/prisma";
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";

export default async function handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
  if (req.method === 'POST') {
    try {
      const { id, name, email, password } = req.body;

      // Check if the user already exists (you may need to customize this logic)
      const existingUser = await prisma.user.findUnique({
        where: { email },
      });

      if (existingUser) {
        return res.status(400).json({ error: 'User already exists' });
      }

      // Create a new user using Prisma
      const newUser = await prisma.user.create({
        data: {
          id,
          name,
          email,
          password, // Note: You should hash the password before saving it to the database
        },
      });

      return res.status(201).json(newUser);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Server error' });
    }
  } else {
    return res.status(405).json({ error: 'Method not allowed' });
  }
}
```

and this is for the frontend part

```
"use client";

import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function SignUp() {
  const [id, setId] = useState("");
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

  const handleSubmit = async (e: { preventDefault: () => void; }) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const user = await fetch("/api/auth/signup", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ id, name, email, password }),
    });
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} method="POST">
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="username"
        value={id}
        onChange={(e) => setId(e.target.value)}
      />

      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="name"
        value={name}
        onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
      />

      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="email"
        value={email}
        onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
      />

      <input
        type="password"
        placeholder="password"
        value={password}
        onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
      />

      <button type="submit">Sign Up</button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

I asked chatgpt for assistance with this code though since I am really beginner to webdev frameworks and I am bad at thinking algorithims

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have mistaken `app` and `pages` router in Next.js 13. To use client/server components, you need to use `app` router.

But your `src\app\api\auth\signup\route.ts` hanlder is created for the `pages` router, which will not work with `app` router. That is why you get the error:

```
` ⨯ Detected default export in 'C:\Users\USER\Desktop\myWorks\webdevproj\loginsys\src\app\api\auth\signup\route.ts'. Export a named export for each HTTP method instead.⨯ No HTTP methods exported in 'C:\Users\USER\Desktop\myWorks\webdevproj\loginsys\src\app\api\auth\signup\route.ts'. Export a named export for each HTTP method.
```

To fix this error, you need to convert this handler to one compatible with `app` router, like:

```
export async function POST(request: Request) {
    try {
        const { id, name, email, password } = req.body;

        // Check if the user already exists (you may need to customize this logic)
        const existingUser = await prisma.user.findUnique({
            where: { email },
        });

        if (existingUser) {
            return res.status(400).json({ error: 'User already exists' });
        }

        // Create a new user using Prisma
        const newUser = await prisma.user.create({
            data: {
                id,
                name,
                email,
                password, // Note: You should hash the password before saving it to the database
           },
        });

        return res.status(201).json(newUser);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Server error' });
    }
}
```

Refer https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-handlers for more details.

Comment: it worked sir! thank you so much! 